# Update Amazon Linux to current version

Tags: amazon-ec2

When I ssh into my EC2 instance I get the following message:

```
https://aws.amazon.com/amazon-linux-ami/2012.09-release-notes/
Amazon Linux version 2014.03 is available.
```

I'd love to update to 2014.03 but don't know how. Would I have to wipe out my installed software and services to do so (I have a Nexus server running on Apache on that system)?  I've run "sudo yum update" and it just says "No Packages marked for Update".  I've also googled and searched this site but not found anything clearly helpful.  Admittedly my knowledge of yum and AMIs is pretty minimal as I'm not a sysadmin by trade, just trying to maintain a couple of EC2 instances hosting website and development resources.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

Did you reboot? Check the documentation: http://aws.amazon.com/amazon-linux-ami/2014.03-release-notes/